# Replacing a file with a new file of the same name but different content in TFS via C#

Tags: c#, replace, tfs

i´m currently working on a programm which updates templates on our companies Team Foundation Server. I am having those new templates locally on my disk and want to replace the existing ones on the server. I was trying different approaches and this is my newest version. The problem is that either

1. the new file is "in use" when accessing it through coding in c#(while not in use when i try to replace it in runtime using the normal explorer).
2. the replacement is not appearing in the pending changes, the pendingChanges array is initial.

   ```
       using (var tfs = TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer("myserver"))
       {
           var versionControlServer = tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer)) as VersionControlServer;  

           // Create a new workspace for the currently authenticated user.    

           var workspace = versionControlServer.CreateWorkspace("Temporary Workspace", versionControlServer.AuthorizedUser);

           try
           {
               // Check if a mapping already exists.
               var workingFolder = new WorkingFolder("$serverpath", @"c:\tempFolder");

               // Create the mapping (if it exists already, it just overides it, that is fine).
               workspace.CreateMapping(workingFolder);
               workspace.Get(VersionSpec.Latest, GetOptions.GetAll);

               string[] paths = new string[1];
               paths[0] = "test.pdf";

               workspace.PendEdit(paths, RecursionType.Full, null, LockLevel.None);


               // Go through the folder structure defined and create it locally, then check in the changes.
               CreateFolderStructure(workspace, workingFolder.LocalItem);

               // Check in the changes made.                    
               int a = workspace.CheckIn(workspace.GetPendingChanges(), "This is my comment");
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
           }
           finally
           {
               // Cleanup the workspace.
               workspace.Delete();

               // Remove the temp folder used.
               Directory.Delete(@"C:\tempFolder", true);
           }
       }
   }

   static void CreateFolderStructure(Workspace workspace, string initialPath)
   {            
       workspace.PendDelete("$serverpath/test.pdf", RecursionType.None);

       File.Copy(@"C:\test\testnew.pdf", @"C:\tempfolder\test", true);
       workspace.PendAdd(@"C:\tempfolder\test.pdf");  
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem. The workspace which was used by "authorizedUser" was obviously not enough.. I found out that a need a TeamFoundationIdentity to do it. Here is a guide on how to fix the issue.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/taylaf/archive/2010/03/29/using-tfs-impersonation-with-the-version-control-client-apis.aspx